# let $f$ be a convex function, homogeneous of degree 1, prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^n}, f(-x ) \geq -f(x) $

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

We are given a function ${f \colon   \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\}$. $ f $ is a convex function ,also homogeneous of degree $1$  . So for every  $t  \geq 0 $, $ f(tx)= tf(x)$. Now we want to prove that : $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^n}, f(-x ) \geq -f(x) $

The hint for this exercise is that i should use the property of convex functions that says : $ \forall t \in [0,1]\hspace{0.5cm}    \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}, \hspace{0.5cm} f(tx + (1-t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y) $

From this point i don't know how to end the demonstration since i can't use the homogeneous of degree 1 property because $-1$ is negative. Please give me a hint on how i can from the previous expression to $f(-x ) \geq -f(x) $ . Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried $y= -x$ and $t = 1/2$?

Comment: Hint: $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Ok i have found the solution thanks to you both. First i had to say $y= -x$ and $t= 1/2$. Then after replacing it in the expression, i could conclude by using the fact that $f(0) = 0$. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we need that $f(0) = 0$, which follows from the homogeneity. Then
$$
 0 = f(0) = f\left( \frac{(-x) + x}{2}\right)\le \frac{f(-x) + f(x)}{2}
$$
implies $f(-x ) \geq -f(x)$.